# How add rails helper without editing files in app/helpers/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper

I (try to) write all ruby code related to my rails application in the app/lib/
folder. The lib folder is structured like how a ruby gem would structure it's lib hierarchy.
(As a sidenote, this gives me 2 benefits. I can auto generate documentation by running `yardoc app/lib`. I can also have my test/ folder resemble the app/lib/ folder, which was what was recommended by a few blog posts on the topic.)

My issue is, I wanted to add a helper to the rails views. And I was forced to edit the `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` and add `include Mynamespace::Myhelpers`

How can I tell rails about my helpers, without touching anything outside of the app/lib/ folder.

Comment: If you’re putting all of your code logic in `app/lib` instead of in `app/controllers`, `app/models`, `app/helpers`, etc., then you may be working against the Rails framework rather than with it. Yes, there is often code in a project which doesn’t apply to any of the preset directories, but any code that does match the purpose of a given directory should probably go in it. If you’re writing a helper method, it should really be in `app/helpers` (or at least have a wrapper method in that directory that refers to your custom code elsewhere).

Comment: Rails uses "convention over configuration." To break the convention, you are asking us how to add that extra configuration back in.